# How to activate a Powerpoint Presentation through Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to use macros to put pictures into Powerpoints, as the last stage of a larger macro in excel.

If I put the following code through PowerPoint VBA, it works fine, but if I try put the same code through Excel (after adding the reference) I get this error message :

**Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method**

The code I am using is :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim applPP As PowerPoint.Application, prsntPP As PowerPoint.Presentation,   TitlePage As PowerPoint.Slide

            Set applPP = New PowerPoint.Application
            applPP.Visible = True
            Set prsntPP = applPP.Presentations.Add
            Set TitlePage = prsntPP.Slides.Add(Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutTitle)

            Dim oSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
            Dim oPicture As PowerPoint.Shape

            Set oSlide = ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(1)

            Set oPicture = oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg", _
                msoFalse, msoTrue, 1, 2, 3, 4)

            oPicture.ScaleHeight 0.9, msoTrue
            oPicture.ScaleWidth 0.9, msoTrue

            With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
                oPicture.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (oPicture.Width \ 2)
                oPicture.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (oPicture.Height \ 2)
            End With
        End Sub
```

And am getting an error pop up on "Set oSlide = ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(1)"

Can anyone explain to me why this is, and suggest a fix?
Thanks,
Btubnfj

Comment: You are getting that error because of `ActiveWindow`. Where are you binding with the powerpoint application and presentation?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the fast reply! Here is the code which goes just before the first dim. Been messing around with this code, and forgot to re-add this part... Original post has been updated. I hope that's what you meant - am new to VBA

Comment: Have you used the VBA debugger to figure out which property or method and which object this error message is referring to? That is also helpful information for us to help you :)

Comment: @MichaelSPriz I get the error message after "Set oSlide = ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(1)".

Comment: Change `Set oSlide = ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(1)` to `Set oSlide = prsntPP.Slides(1)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I thought I'd tried lots of things, including that, but apparently not! It works now, thanks a lot :D

Comment: glad it worked... similarly.. change `With ActivePresentation.PageSetup` to `With prsntPP.PageSetup`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yup, that bugged up, and I corrected it. Really pleased to have it working, as I've been trying lots of potential solutions over the past few hours, but nothing working.